# Breakpoints with Angular in Intellij Ultimate 2020.1

Tags: angular, gradle, intellij-idea, jhipster

I have Intellij Ultimate 2020.1 and are trying to debug a Angular project. The build tool is gradle.

When I use Intellij to set a breakpoint on a event trigger, it doesn't stop code execution. How do I fix this?

[image]

I am using gradle for the build tool. The project is generated in jhipster.

Comment: Have you run your debug using chrome plugin within Intelij. And are you using Webstorm

Comment: does debugging work for you in Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: I don't know about IntelliJ but Chrome Debugger extension for Visual Studio Code works fine https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-angular-cli-applications-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

To Debu using IntelliJ, I recommend using Webstorm IDE. you can't debug front end applications by using IntelliJ. you can run front end projects outside, but not the debugging. You can setup your IDE like this with any browser you want. but from experience Chrome is more supportive of debugging.
Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This is plain wrong. You can setup remote Javascript debugging with IntelliJ. It will use Chrome to open your frontend application and you can stop at a breakpoint in Angular code.